# If in htaccess for 301 Redirect special characters anywhere in URL to another characters?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Rule: Redirecting all URLs that contains `%252C+` to `,-` and redirecting `+` to `-` only if the `+` comes with `%252C+`.

e.g1: `http://www.example.com/FortWorth%252C+TX/`
  to: `http://www.example.com/FortWorth,-TX/`

e.g2: `http://www.example.com/Fort+Worth%252C+TX/`
  to: `http://www.example.com/Fort-Worth,-TX/`

e.g3: `http://www.example.com/Fort+Worth/`
  to: `http://www.example.com/Fort+Worth/`
      (Should not redirect this one)

Note: Please remember your code should not be only for the above URL but for all URLs with the above rule.

Comment: That's a weird double-encoded url...

Comment: True, any idea my friend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Sumurai8 , for your solution but it needs to be modified like This code  :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^+]+)\+(.+)%2C+\+(.*)$ /$1-$2,-$3 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^([^+]+)%2C+\+(.*)$ /$1,-$2 [R,L]
```

Comment: You could just have suggested an edit. I am unsure why you have included an extra `+` behind the C though. OP's code only shows one `C` in the url.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of `RewriteRule` is matched against the %-decoded url, so it should be matched against `http://www.example.com/FortWorth%2C+TX/` for example instead of `http://www.example.com/FortWorth%252C+TX/`.

Assuming the strange substring only occurs once, and the "+" only appears once before that, you can do it with the following two rules. If multiple +'s can occur, things start to turn ugly quickly, because you'll need to either add a lot more rules, or start handling it recursively.

```
RewriteRule ^([^+]+)\+(.+)%2C\+(.*)$ $1-$2,-$3 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^([^+]+)%2C\+(.*)$ $1,-$2 [R,L]
```

I am not sure if mod_rewrite will escape the `,` character as a "special character". It is a valid character to use in an url. If it gives you problems, you could use the `[NE]` flag to prevent escaping such characters.

Comment: Sorry my friend, i can only give you thumbs up, your code redirects to root /